# Add order status while placing order from admin Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, order-status, admin-controller

I want to add a custom dropdown for the order status in the create an order page from admin. Admin can choose the order status while placing the order.
Please see attached screenshot!!!

**Or**

Can i set the custom order status from admin order save controller?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order status once the order has been successfully submitted. To do this you reopen the order and navigate to the comment section.

If you need to have a status that is not built into the system, navigate to 
**System -> Order Statuses**

Information can be found in the [Magento 1.9 Custom Status](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/order-processing/order-status-custom.html) documentation.